# Ideas for Find and Replace character

Tags: mysql, regex, excel

I need to search address fields and change one character to upper case if there is an apartment number. So '521 Main St. #3b' would change to '521 Main St. #3B'.

The way I know to do this would be to write a program that loops through the recordset, looks at the address field for the last character to see if it's an alpha, then if the character before it is a numeric, change the case of the last char and update the record.

Is this something that would be quicker/simpler with regular expressions (haven't ever used)?
If so, is this best done from within a programming environmnet or using a text editor such as Textmate or vi ?  The data is in MySQL and Excel, but I can export it to a text file.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not good with speeds, but what about a recordset that just selects records with the last character as a lower case?  Then run through that set and make each last character `.toUpper`?

Comment: Total # in recordset is ~8000; 4000-6000 need to be changed.

Comment: You can certainly use regex to find the lines that need to be updated, but then you'll want to use something else to modify them.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this using TextMate which, once I began to understand a little regex, was simple. (details here [Regex Syntax for making the last character Uppercase in TextMate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922722/regex-syntax-in-textmate))

Still, I wonder if something like sed or awk, (which I started to try out) might be a better tool. And the SQL solution that Olexa provided works. I just don't know how to have it apply to the entire recordset.

Comment: In my example only the first record is updated, because only it has an apartment number with a lower-case letter at the end. :)

Comment: Hi Olexa, Would you try to update 2-3 records w/ lowercase on SQL Fiddle? I edited the schema but it only updates one. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If the data is stored in MySQL, then it is better to process it there:

```
UPDATE  addresses
  SET   address = CONCAT(LEFT(address, CHAR_LENGTH(address) - 1), UPPER(RIGHT(address, 1)))
  WHERE address REGEXP BINARY '#[[:digit:]]+[[:lower:]]{1}$'
;
```

I've added `BINARY` because otherwise `REGEXP` is not case-sensitive, but `BINARY` may need to be omitted to support multi-byte strings. In this case, surplus updates will be made, but the result would be correct anyway.

P. S. An example on SQL Fiddle showing which values are affected, and how they are affected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b29326/1

Comment: I ran this mysql> UPDATE attRegex SET address = CONCAT(LEFT(address, CHAR_LENGTH(address) - 1), UPPER(RIGHT(address, 1))) WHERE address REGEXP BINARY '#[[:digit:]]+[[:lower:]]{1}$';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

Comment: Added an example on SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for this code and the nifty example Olexa, but it only affects the first record. How do I run the SQL against entire table? Do I need write a program in PHP (for example) and loop through the records or is there another way to make it 'multi-line'?

Comment: An example of updating entire existing column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b093/1 Is this what you'd like to obtain?

Comment: Yes! This works fine and is very helpful. Thanks so much for persisting!