# Regex Syntax for making the last character Uppercase in TextMate

Tags: regex, textmate, oniguruma

I want to uppercase the **last** character in a address field. So for "300 E.87th St. #4b" becomes "300 E.87th St. #4B", but "87th" should not change to 87Th. Can I do that in TextMate? If so, what's the syntax?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `87tH`?  We need more specific rules for when to capitalize

Comment: I want to find a digit followed by an alpha, but only affect the last character in the address field which may be an apartment #. It should capitalize the 'b' but not the 't' (or any other character in the field).

Comment: `\d([a-z])$` may find it

Comment: ([0-9][a-z]$) in the Find field will capture '4b' but \u$1 in the Replace doesn't do anything. I think because the change case only should be applied to 'b', not '4b'. How do I do indicate that? Or am I wrong in thinking the change case action goes in the Replace field?

Comment: In other words, since the capture is '4b', how do indicate change the second char in the capture to uppercase.

Answer (score 6):

The solution was to simply to have two captures in the Find field: ([0-9])([a-z])$
and include both of them in the Replace: $1\U$2.

Kind of obvious, I guess. This was the first time I've needed regex and was trying to solve a problem while learning the basics, a situation that is doubtless quite common!

Comment: that's not working for me, is there a setting to enable?